# Rains and rain distinction

Tags: nouns

According to OALD rain is used as

Uncountable, singular

But when it is used in plural form like ***the rains*** it refers to the season of heavy continuous rain.

But the sentence

> Heavy ***rains*** quenched the fire.

Is correct, although rains is used.

Answer (score 1):

You have not asked a question, but in the [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rain) is

> **rain**
>   NOUN
>   *[mass noun]*
>
> **1.1** (**rains**) Falls of rain.
>   *the plants were washed away by unusually heavy rains*